# Django - cannot migrate after makemigrations

Tags: django, django-migrations

I am not able to migrate this code after makemigrations.

When I type `python manage.py migrate`, it is showing me no migration to apply.

```py
class MyUserManager(BaseUserManager):
    def create_user(self,email,firstname,lastname,password=None):
        if not password:
            raise ValueError("user must have password")
        if not email:
            raise ValueError("User must have an email address")
        user = self.model(
            email=self.normalize_email(email)
            )

        user.set_password(password)
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user

    def create_superuser(self, email, date_of_birth, password=None):
        
        user = self.create_user(
            email,
            password=password,
            
        )
        user.is_admin = True
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user


class MyUser(AbstractBaseUser):
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=100,default="emaple@exampll.com",unique=True)
    firstname = models.CharField(max_length=100,default="FirstName")
    lastname = models.CharField(max_length=100,default="LastName")
    date_of_birth = models.DateField(default=timezone.now)
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    admin = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIERD_FIELDS = []

    objects = MyUserManager()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.firstname + self.lastname
    
    @property
    def is_staff(self):
        return self.staff
    
    @property
    def is_admin(self):
        return self.admin

    @property
    def is_active(self):
        return self.active
```

Answer (score 0):

If it says "no migrations to apply", it means that you don't need to migrate anything and the server is ready to run. You only need to migrate after you committed changes to your database, and if you didn't, you can safely continue to run your server without migrating anything

Answer (score 0):

i found the problem in my code that I was getting ,actually I was using builit user model first and then I decided to code for custom user model , in database the builtin usermodel was working fine and custom usermodel was not migrating.